# WebSphere 9.0.5.7 JDK upgraded to 8.0.6.31 and facing Issue to deploy EAR

Tags: python, java, websphere

After IBM WAS Java upgrade from 8.0.6.11 to 8.0.6.31 the .ear file is not getting deployed using wsadmin.sh script, although the same is getting
deployed successfully using WebSphere console directly.

Some basic detail below:

version info from the server where .ear is deploying successfully:

$ /usr/IBM/WebSphere90/AppServer/bin/versionInfo.sh
WVER0010I: Copyright (c) IBM Corporation 2002, 2012; All rights reserved.
WVER0012I: VersionInfo reporter version 1.15.1.48, dated 2/8/12

---

### IBM WebSphere Product Installation Status Report

Report at date and time December 29, 2021 7:00:42 AM CET

### Installation

Product Directory /usr/IBM/WebSphere90/AppServer
Version Directory /usr/IBM/WebSphere90/AppServer/properties/version
DTD Directory /usr/IBM/WebSphere90/AppServer/properties/version/dtd
Log Directory /var/ibm/InstallationManager/logs

### Product List

JAVA8 installed
ND installed

### Installed Product

Name IBM SDK, Java Technology Edition, Version 8
Version 8.0.6.11
ID JAVA8
Build Level pap6480sr6fp11-20200602_01
Build Date 06/02/20
Architecture PPC64

### Installed Product

Name IBM WebSphere Application Server Network Deployment
Version 9.0.5.7
ID ND
Build Level f5072109.01
Build Date 3/1/21
Package com.ibm.websphere.ND.v90_9.0.5007.20210301_1241
Architecture PPC64
Installed Features WebSphere Application Server traditional
EJBDeploy tool for pre-EJB 3.0 modules
Embeddable EJB container
Stand-alone thin clients and resource adapters

---

### End Installation Status Report

version info from the server where .ear deploy is stuck:

$ /usr/IBM/WebSphere90/AppServer/bin/versionInfo.sh
WVER0010I: Copyright (c) IBM Corporation 2002, 2012; All rights reserved.
WVER0012I: VersionInfo reporter version 1.15.1.48, dated 2/8/12

---

### IBM WebSphere Product Installation Status Report

Report at date and time December 29, 2021 7:01:56 AM CET

### Installation

Product Directory /usr/IBM/WebSphere90/AppServer
Version Directory /usr/IBM/WebSphere90/AppServer/properties/version
DTD Directory /usr/IBM/WebSphere90/AppServer/properties/version/dtd
Log Directory /var/ibm/InstallationManager/logs

### Product List

JAVA8 installed
ND installed

### Installed Product

Name IBM SDK, Java Technology Edition, Version 8
Version 8.0.6.31
ID JAVA8
Build Level pap6480sr6fp31-20210510_01
Build Date 05/10/21
Architecture PPC64

### Installed Product

Name IBM WebSphere Application Server Network Deployment
Version 9.0.5.7
ID ND
Build Level f5072109.01
Build Date 3/1/21
Package com.ibm.websphere.ND.v90_9.0.5007.20210301_1241
Architecture PPC64
Installed Features WebSphere Application Server traditional
EJBDeploy tool for pre-EJB 3.0 modules
Embeddable EJB container
Stand-alone thin clients and resource adapters

---

### End Installation Status Report

Since no logs is getting generated we cannot determine the exact reason for the stuck. At times it gives heap memory issue but even after increasing
the heap size the deployment still gets stuck. And we have noticed this behaviour after upgrade of WebSphere JDK 8.0.6.31. Once we downgrade the JDK back
to 8.0.6.11 the same ear is getting deployed successfully using wsadmin.sh script.

We would need your help and advise on this..!!

Comment: But what error you are getting while installing the application???

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.